# How many surjections are there from $\{1, 2, 3, ..., n\}$ to $\{1, 2\}$ if $n \geq 3$?

Tags: combinatorics, functions, elementary-set-theory

I just completed an exam and was curious as to the following question:

> How many surjections are there from $\{1, 2, 3, ..., n\}$ to $\{1, 2\}$ if $n \geq 3$?

My assumption was the following:

The first element of the domain has the possibility to map to either 1 or 2.

The second element then has the possibility to map to the opposite element of the codomain, in which the first element hasn't mapped to.

Now the functions are surjective, and then any remaining elements of the domain ($n-2$ of them) can then map to either of the 2 elements of the codomain.

My answer was $2^{n-1}$. Is this answer correct? Is there a fallacy in my thought process?

Comment: Nice question from Rajesh's Final exam I see. (I am in the same class as you)

Comment: Yeah, I had noticed earlier some questions pertaining to his assignments, which I so hopelessly screwed up.

Comment: The formula $2^n - 2$ also works when $n = 2$ since $2^2 - 2 = 4 - 2 = 2!$, which is the number of bijections from a set with two elements to itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically you can think of it as a binary string, $0$ means the element in the domain maps to the first element in the codomain, $1$ means the element maps to the second element in the codomain. There are $2^n$ ways to make a binary string of length $n$, but with the rules of surjectivity we need to take away the case where everything maps to the first element, and everything maps to the second element, so our final answer should be $2^n - 2$.

Answer (score 0):

You had some of the right ideas, but you are not quite right. Let's start with finding the number of functions from ${1,2,...,n}$ to ${1,2}$ without any restrictions on the function. Then each of the numbers $1,2,...,n$ can be mapped to either $1$ or $2$, and there are hence $2^n$ such functions. How many of these are not surjective? For the function not to be surjective, it would have to map every number to $1$, or to map every number to $2$. Hence there are exactly $2$ non-surjective functions, and the answer to the question is $2^n-2$.